# AWS Data Pipeline access S3

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm using AWS Data Pipeline to copy files from S3 into an AWS Redshift table.  The folder structure on S3 is as follows:

```
s3://test/folderA
s3://test/example=01
s3://test/example=02
s3://test/example=03
s3://test/example=04
```

I want to be able to copy the all files in the 'example=##' folders but not the 'folderA'

Any ideas how to do this? Regex in Data Pipeline doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Note that, despite this being an absurd limitation, using the S3DataNode with a copy activity only works for csv and tsv files: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-s3datanode.html

Answer (score 0):

Data Pipeline invokes the Redshift COPY command to load S3 files into Redshift. The S3 path can just be the prefix of the files you want. You can look at the documentation here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_loading-tables-from-s3.html

If you want to write your own Redshift COPY command you can SqlActivity against a Redshift connection. https://github.com/awslabs/data-pipeline-samples/tree/master/samples/SQLActivityWithTimeout

Answer (score 0):

If there are many files, it seems that a manifest file is the best choice:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-s3datanode.html

If there are only a few files, I would use an expression for the S3 filename: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-pipeline-expressions.html
with user defined fields. Create several on demand pipe executions with different values.